# Private and public methods in RequireJS objects

Tags: javascript, properties, methods, private, requirejs

I'm not certain how to set methods private or public when using requirejs, as it uses shorthand for object declaration. In the following code, I would prefer if the property "id" and the method "prepareId" were private.

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    var Asset = Class.extend({
        init: function() {
            this.id = "12345";
        }
        ,getAsset: function() {
          return this.prepareId(this.id);
        }
        ,prepareId: function(id) {
          return "#" + id;
        }
    });
    return Asset;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are slightly confused. require.js does not impose rules on what you return. If you want to return a constructor that creates "private" attributes and functions you can do so.

So the following (if I understand correctly what you mean by private) should work just fine.

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
  var Asset = function () {
    var id;
    function prepareId(id) {
      ...
    };
    ...
  };
  return Asset;

});
```

Comment: You can also declare any private vars/methods outside of the constructor by using the pattern outlined on the RequireJS docs - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc

Comment: Sorry my reply is delayed, I'm trying to figure out the value of reusing John Resig's example for [simple javascript inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) for my application.